# spring, use HikariCP VS c3p0 ,same code, different result

Tags: spring, c3p0, hikaricp

Environment

```
HikariCP version: HikariCP-java7 2.4.13
JDK version     : 1.7.0_080
Database        : PostgreSQL
Driver version  : 9.1-901.jdbc3
```

spring, use HikariCP VS c3p0 ,same code, different results

```
  @Transactional
   public Integer enableItem(Long id){

       //change item status from 0 to 1
       Integer result = itemDao.enableItem(id);

       //load item

       //if c3p0 , item status is new value 1
       // but Hikari, item status still is 0
       Item item = itemDao.findItemById(id);
       return result;
   }
```

In the same transaction, first change the item status from 0 to 1, and then read the latest item information, if c3p0 , item status is new value 1 , **but Hikari, item status still is 0**

Hikari config:

```
    <property name="driverClassName" value="#{meta['dataSource.driverClassName']}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{meta['dataSource.url']}" />
    <property name="username" value="#{meta['dataSource.username']}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{meta['dataSource.password']}" />
    <property name="readOnly" value="false" />

    <property name="idleTimeout" value="#{meta['dataSource.maxIdleTime']}" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000" /> 
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="#{meta['dataSource.maxPoolSize']}" />

    <property name="minimumIdle" value="#{meta['dataSource.minPoolSize']}" />
</bean>
```

I expect to get the latest value with Hikari. Is there any problem with the configuration?

see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1522

Comment: Why do you use so old versions (Java 7 and Hikari 2)? The latest versions are Java 17 and Hikari 5. So your testing results may differ

Answer (score 1):

These 2 connection pools probably have different default values for the transaction isolation level.

Try adding
`<property name="transactionIsolation" value="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED"`